# Can't connect to Tomcat via USB tethering

Tags: android, debugging, tomcat, connection, usb

[image: eclipse error message]

Eclipse logcatil shows like this when I try to connect my phone through USB debugging. When I run my application in emulator using 10.0.2.2, localhost address it works well.

But unfortunately I can't access Tomcat when connecting my phone.

Answer (score 0):

*First you should Install Connectifyme Software.After inatalling that open that application and connect your mobile to that.after connected to your mobile just place your cursor on connectify me (opened application) you will get an URL. Instead of localhost just give that ip address in u r mobile.u r tomcat will work in u r mobile.I Hope this will works u. *